# Modify Collation of a column

Tags: mysql-8.0, collation

mysql  Ver 8.0.25

Got this error in apache log:

> Error query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' In query: SELECT `idaction`, `type`, `name` FROM matomo_log_action WHERE ( hash = CRC32(?) AND name = ? AND type = ? ) [...]

This is the table's info:

```
mysql> SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM matomo_log_action;
+------------+------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field      | Type             | Collation          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+------------+------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| idaction   | int unsigned     | NULL               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| name       | varchar(4096)    | utf8mb4_unicode_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| hash       | int unsigned     | NULL               | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| type       | tinyint unsigned | NULL               | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| url_prefix | tinyint          | NULL               | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+------------+------------------+--------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

Now I think I need to modify the `Collation` of field `type` to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, but don't know how:

`mysql> ALTER TABLE matomo_log_action MODIFY type tinyint unsigned CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1

Comment: The column `type` is numeric, and charset/collation is not applicable to it. *Now I think I need to modify the Collation of field type to utf8mb4_unicode_ci* ?? Why do you think so? The error message shows that you'd modify the column `name`.

Comment: .. or, if the collation explicitly assigned to `name` is critical, modify the string literal which is provided as query parameter. Like ```.. AND name = ? COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci AND ..```

Comment: Thx for these insights! Will try out your second proposal since the column is huge (>20GB) and also the assigned collation may be critical as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is about `matomo` using the db I ended up fixing this with this `matomo` command:

```
./console core:convert-to-utf8mb4
```

This command i.a. did log this:

```
ALTER TABLE `matomo_log_action` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

That changed the collation of `matomo_log_action.name` to `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` and the error did not appear again.